# Google Analytics doesn't track every Facebook posts

Tags: php, google-analytics, analytics

I have a website that's getting visitors from my facebook posts, and on that site I have installed Google Analytics code which works well, I've seen users get on the website while running a Facebook Ad Campaign, but now that I've stopped that and users are coming through page's posts, GA is only tracking "some of them" whilst my custom unique views tracker on the website (PHP) is tracking much more views.

99% of the views come from the mobile app.

I think it might have to do with maybe Facebook opening the links on it's own webview and for some reason GA code is not getting called.

Is that possible? Has anyone found similar inconsistencies?

Answer (score 0):

I wannted to add this as a comment but i can't due the extension.

When the user opens a link on the app the document.referrer is set as undefined (I tested on Iphones only). So it's not possible to determine the source by default. ¿Are you using UTM tags?. In this case is mandatory to determine the origin of the source.

Also remember that Google Analytics uses the cookie to store the navigation information. If your browser in app is different can happens other cases, for example, the user clicks on the Ads and use the in-App browser (not the regular one) and then comes back using Safari. you will get 2 differents users. Add a little more of information, how and where you have the code, are you using utm, some screenshot hiding sensitive data.

Greetings